# Spring Boot JSP not found

Tags: spring, jsp, heroku, spring-boot

in my Spring Boot app I switched from Thymeleaf to JSP and it is working normally on my local computer, but when I upload it to Heroku server I get
        `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp`

its jar packaged, what does it mean if its working locally but not on Heroku server?

edit, project structure
[image]

Comment: can you share your folder structure, showing where you kept the jsp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this to `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and adding this to `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and moving JSPs to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`.

Comment: Moving JSP's to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` solved the problem. Thanks a lot.