# Page is not loading on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I'm trying to build a spring boot application and when i load a jsp page it shows 404 error
i'm using jasper to load the jsp below is my code
Main File

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

controller file

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

properties file

```
server.port=8000
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
```

dependencies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.38</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

when i run the app and access `http://localhost:8000/home` gives me a `404`
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you placed your `WEB-INF` folder in project structure? The correct placement of `WEB-INF` is

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp
```

Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685114/2614885

Comment: i placed the webapp folder on `src/main/resources` now it's working thanks